# Dynamic querying of translated keywords

Tags: tridion

I'm trying to use the dynamic query api to determine if components are available in Tridion based upon a users audience manager profile.

One of these fields in their profile is 'Country' - which is recorded as free text in the extended details part of the audience manager profile, but based on a keyword from a 'Countries' category. We cannot store it as a keyword unfortunately due to client requirements.

It's expected that certain forms on the website being developed will be pre-filled using profile information from audience manager, for example pre-selecting a users country from a dropdown menu.

My concern is that if the 'Countries' category is translated in another publication, it would be impossible to pre-populate countries dropdown menus on forms because of the translated country names would be different.

Is that the case, or is it possible to translate and audience manager profile as well?

Comment: None of that is an issue if you would just use the Keywords. So I have to question the statement "We cannot store it as a keyword unfortunately due to client requirements." What requirements would that be? It doesn't make sense to try all kinds of strange workarounds when there is perfectly good out-of-the-box functionality you can use :)

Comment: I'm with Peter on this. "unfortunately due to client requirements" isn't helping us to understand the problem. What is the underlying requirement? Maybe we can point out a better way to satisfy it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the local keyword (the Chinese one in your example). From there you can do a "Using Items" look up to find the Parent Keyword. I don't have the specific code, but if you check in the GUI, you can see the parent in the Used Items tab if you do a Where Used on the localised Keyword.

Comment: That sounds like a useful technique, but I wonder if you'd want the parent, or perhaps instead, the ancestor in a specific publication?

Comment: Good question. You could also do a "Used Items" look up to find any localised versions in child Publications ;)

Comment: That would work in the TOM.NET API, but unfortunately I'm dealing with the Content Delivery API for this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how specific this is to Audience manager. Isn't it more of a general blueprinting question? As you say, if you translate the country names keywords, the translated values are, of course, what will be published to the content delivery system. It may make sense to use the translated values in your site; otherwise why would you translate them?

If there are good reasons for wanting to use the untranslated values, then you can easily do this by publishing also from the parent publication, and writing your queries to operate in the context of that publication. As you have both values available, you can build your programme logic to make use of whichever one makes sense, and still have the benefit of a clear relationship between the two.

Comment: I think you're right in saying it is more of a blueprinting issue, as it could effect more than just prepopulating form values based on translated keywords. What I've realised is that I need to use the tcm uri of keywords to identify them across different language publications, but unfortunately it's just the translated keyword value that's being stored in audience manager profiles. I gues there could be a way of deterring which publication the keyword came from, but it would be great if tridion offered a way of retrieving a keyword just using its value, even if it's been translated

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieving a keywork just using its value"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, so if I wanted to retrieve a keyword specified in the English publication like 'United States' for example, but was working from within the Chinese publication, I couldn't use something like taxonomy factory from the content delivery api to retrieve the Chinese version of the keyword just using its English name? Looking at I don't think the api offers a way to retrieve keywords just using a value, unless retrieving an entire category and looping through all the keywords to find a matching value